# Postgres - LIKE ANY UPPER()

Tags: postgresql, case

Is there a way to use UPPER with a LIKE ANY()?

I have the following example:

```
SELECT
....
where skus.number like any ('{"%00130204%", "%00130202"}')
```

Unfortunately the skus I'm checking here can be of different cases, so I tried doing this:

```
SELECT
....
where UPPER(skus.number) like any UPPER('{"%00130204%", "%00130202"}'))
```

Which doesn't work, is there any way to get this working in the query itself?

Comment: Usually this type of thing is done to make the "like" case insensitive. Why not just use ilike instead of like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use upper. Use the case insensitive version of like, "ilike" instead.

```
 SELECT
 ....
 where skus.number ilike any ('{"%00130204%", "%00130202"}')
```

Answer (score 0):

along with being totally with @Joe on his answer as better for you query (and skipping phylosophy behind idea to represent digits in uppercase), I decided to answer the topic of your post

> Is there a way to use UPPER with a LIKE ANY()?

yes - here it is:

```
t=# select UPPER('110013020411') like any (UPPER('{"%00130204%", "%00130202"}')::text[]) comaprison;
 comaprison
------------
 t
(1 row)
```

after you upper text in array represented as text you need to cast it back inorder to use with `ANY (array)`